# What alternatives are there to takeUntil with redux-observable and RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I've started porting some async logic to redux-observables and I'm struggling a little with this.

My use case is this:
I have a UI overlay that's supposed to open on an `OPEN_OVERLAY` action, and automatically close after three seconds (by emitting `CLOSE_OVERLAY`) UNLESS either an `INTERRUPT_CLOSE_OVERLAY1` or `INTERRUPT_CLOSE_OVERLAY2` action is received, in which case the overlay shouldn't close.

My first take was this:

```
export const epic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    filter(action => action.type === "OPEN_OVERLAY"), 
    delay(3000), 
    takeUntil(action$.ofType("INTERRUPT_CLOSE_OVERLAY1", "INTERRUPT_CLOSE_OVERLAY2")),
    mapTo({type: "CLOSE_OVERLAY})
);
```

Which works, but just once. That is, if you open the overlay and interrupt it, then after closing and opening it again it will never auto-close.

I understand that this happens because `takeUntil` effectively unsubscribes from the Observable. However the way I understand it with redux-observables you only define the epic once at setup and you're not supposed to be subscribing/unsubscribing.

So, how would I structure this that open/close/autoclose always works without unsubscribing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here would be my approach:

```js
actions$.pipe(
  filter(action => action.type === "OPEN_OVERLAY"), 
  switchMap(
    () => timer(3000)
      .pipe(
        mapTo({ type: "CLOSE_OVERLAY" }),
        takeUntil(action$.ofType("INTERRUPT_CLOSE_OVERLAY1", "INTERRUPT_CLOSE_OVERLAY2")),
      )
  )
)
```

It starts the timer when `"OPEN_OVERLAY"` is emitted, then if the observable provided to `takeUntil` does not emit in the meanwhile, it will successfully emit `"CLOSE_OVERLAY"`. Otherwise, the **inner observable** will complete, so there is no way it can emit unless `"OPEN_OVERLAY"` *restarts* it.